# npm install fails on clone of ag-grid-ng2-example

Tags: angular, npm-install, ag-grid

I am trying to run a trial of ag-Grid on Angular2

I did a

git clone https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2-example.git

And am trying to follow the instructions in the README
To build:

- `npm install`
- `npm install tsd -g`
- `tsd install es6-shim`
- `npm run tsc`

I am getting an error on the first step in the README

I have a working npm and have other Angular2 projects that work without problem
BUT this is the first time I have tried the RC-1 (have been working on beta-15 and
beta-7)
I am getting:

(NOTE I ADDED A SPACE AFTER THE https IN THE BELOW PASTE TO 
prevent them from being links)

npm http GET https ://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap

npm http GET https ://registry.npmjs.org/lite-server

npm http GET https ://registry.npmjs.org/concurrently

npm http GET https ://registry.npmjs.org/es6-shim

npm http 404 https ://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http/2.0.0-rc.1

npm http 404 https ://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler/2.0.0-rc.1

npm ERR! 404 'angular' is not in the npm registry.

npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64

npm ERR! command "node" "/bin/npm" "install"

npm ERR! cwd /home/pwd/src/ag-grid-ng2-example

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.42

npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6

npm ERR! code E404

npm http 200 https ://registry.npmjs.org/ag-grid-enterprise

npm http 404 https ://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platf...2.0.0-rc.1

npm http 404 https ://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router/2.0.0-rc.1

npm http GET https ://registry.npmjs.org/ag-grid-enter...-4.1.4.tgz

npm http 404 https ://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core/2.0.0-rc.1

npm http 404 https ://registry.npmjs.org/angular/route...2.0.0-rc.1

npm http 404 https ://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platf...2.0.0-rc.1

npm http 404 https ://registry.npmjs.org/angular/upgrade/2.0.0-rc.1

This is a fresh git clone as of
Latest commit bad5317

Comment: you just need to indent in markdown to render as code block

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to current version of node.js on your system.You'll need to upgrade your node and npm installation. At least, I was getting the same error just now while using node 0.10 and npm, and now I've upgraded to node 6.0.0 and npm 3.8.6 then everything is working fine.
For updating node you can install latest version of node from official site.

[NodeJs Download](https://nodejs.org/en/)

For Fedora the process is:

To get the latest node.js run the following as root:

curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -

yum remove -y nodejs npm

yum install -y nodejs

Answer (score 0):

or Fedora the process is:

To get the latest node.js run the following as root:

curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -

yum remove -y nodejs npm

yum install -y nodejs